# How to change markers colour in geojson

Tags: json, styles, geojson

I wanna change marker color for in geojson. However, this code doesn't work as expected.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-2.5555, 53.6666]
      },
      "style": {
          "color": "red",
          "weight": 5,
          "opacity": 0.65
      },
      "properties": {}
    }
  ]
}
```